# WPF. MVVM. Как сохранить состояние Checked массива toggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть коллекция `radiobutton`, по нажатии на каждую такую кнопку формируется коллекция `togglebutton`. Данные для формирования и того и другого списка берутся из `viewModel` с помощью `binding`.

Есть ли способ сохранять состояния нажатых кнопок для каждой `togglebutton`. В идеале хотелось бы подсвечивать те `radiobutton`, для которых выбрана хоть одна `toggle`.

```
<!--Список радиокнопок-->

<ItemsControl Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Name="InDiamVM"
              Margin="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RebarsView}">

    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton GroupName="InDiam"
                                     Content="{Binding}"
                                     Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ManageCurrntInDiamCommand, ElementName=InDiamVM}"
                                     Name="InDiamButtonVM"
                                     Style="{StaticResource StyleToggle}"
                                     Margin="1"
                                     Padding="2">

                <RadioButton.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandParameterConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="InDiamButtonVM"
                                         Path="Content" />
                        <Binding ElementName="InDiamButtonVM"
                                         Path="Name" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RadioButton.CommandParameter>
            </RadioButton>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<!--Список togglebutton-->
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="3"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Name="OutDiamVM"
                            Margin="2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding OutDiameters}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding }"
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ManageCurrntOutDiamCommand, ElementName=OutDiamVM}"
                                        Name="OutDiamButtonVM"
                                        Margin="1"
                                        Padding="2">

                <ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandParameterConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="OutDiamButtonVM"
                                         Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="OutDiamButtonVM"
                                         Path="Content" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть viewModel, что отвечает за представление

```
// DependencyProperty для коллекции radiobutton
public ICollectionView RebarsView
{
    get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(RebarsViewProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RebarsViewProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RebarsView.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty RebarsViewProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RebarsView", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(AnchorageViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));



// DependencyProperty для выбранной кнопки radiobutton  
public RebarProperties FocusedRebar
{
    get { return (RebarProperties)GetValue(FocusedRebarProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FocusedRebarProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FocusedRebar.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedRebarProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FocusedRebar", typeof(RebarProperties), typeof(AnchorageViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));


// Команда для получения нужной коллекции в зависимости от положения radiobutton
public RelayCommand ManageCurrntInDiamCommand { get; private set; }

public void ManageCurrntInDiam(object o)
{
    var parameters = o as object[];
    FocusedRebar = parameters[0] as RebarProperties;
    if (FocusedSteel == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Выборка нужного массива для формирования коллекции togglebutton
    OutDiameters = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FocusedSteel.DiametersPermitted.Where(s => s.Diameter <= FocusedRebar.Diameter));
}


// DependencyProperty для коллекции togglebutton
public ICollectionView OutDiameters
{
    get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(OutDiametersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OutDiametersProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for OutDiameters.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty OutDiametersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("OutDiameters", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(AnchorageViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

// DependencyProperty для коллекции выбранных toggle button
public ObservableCollection<RebarProperties> currentOutDiams = new ObservableCollection<RebarProperties>();

public RelayCommand ManageCurrntOutDiamCommand { get; private set; }

public void ManageCurrntOutDiam(object o)
{

    var parameters = o as object[];
    if ((bool)parameters[0] == true)
    {
        if (SteelToDiam.ContainsKey(FocusedSteel))
        {
            if (SteelToDiam[FocusedSteel].ContainsKey(FocusedRebar))
            {
                SteelToDiam[FocusedSteel][FocusedRebar].Add(parameters[1] as RebarProperties);
            }
            else
            {
                SteelToDiam[FocusedSteel].Add(FocusedRebar, new HashSet<RebarProperties>() { parameters[1] as RebarProperties });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SteelToDiam.Add(FocusedSteel, new Dictionary<RebarProperties, HashSet<RebarProperties>>()
                {
                    {FocusedRebar,  new HashSet<RebarProperties>() { parameters[1] as RebarProperties }}
                });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SteelToDiam[FocusedSteel][FocusedRebar].Remove(parameters[1] as RebarProperties);
    }
    // метод, который реализует обновление информации (в data grid, где она отображается)
    UpdateInfo();
}
```

Comment: `Есть коллекция radiobutton, по нажатии на каждую такую кнопку формируется коллекция togglebutton.` - покажете? Если я правильно это понял, то у вас не каким MVVM и не пахнет...

Comment: Возможно вопрос не затрагивает MVVM. У меня реализован ViewModel, который дергает из Логики обсчитанные данные. Мне хотелось бы либо во ViewModel  либо непосредственно в xaml делать то что в вопросе: хранить состояние кликнутых toggle button.

Comment: `Возможно вопрос не затрагивает MVVM` - а стоит метка MVVM, да и пытаетесь вы использовать MVVM подход ведь, как тогда это `не затрагивает`? Ну а раз у вас все по MVVM, то забудьте про View, представьте что у вас его попросту нету. Как бы вы реализовали это в коде из примитивных объектов (int/string/bool... и class)?

Comment: А вы попробуйте сделать словарь. Ключ это `RadioButton`, а значение -  `List<ToggleButtons>`. И при изменении состояния хоть одного RadioButton обновлять данные - изменять состояние ToggleButton на те которые в словаре по ключу активного RadioButton. Должно работать

Comment: И если не трудно, и позволяет состояние проекта, можете оставить ссылку на файл **xaml** что бы можно было самому ответ подготовить

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Постараюсь реализовать идею со словарем. Проект делается в учебных целях, поэтому прилагаю [ссылку](https://mega.nz/#F!0gxnkayS!gdFzPYDoqjJTDEJBEV6msQ) на него